# Conditional array.join in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings and I would like to display them as a comma separated string but add "and" for the last element. For example I have

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.join(' ,');
```

outputs

```
'Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango'
```

Is there any way the I add "and" for the last word so it outputs

```
'Banana, Orange, Apple and Mango'
```

Comment: You can use `.reduce` or replace the last comma in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```js
var delimiter = ', ';
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.join(delimiter); 
var index = energy.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
energy = energy.substring(0, index) + ' and ' + energy.substring(index + delimiter.length);

console.log(energy);
```

Comment: Thank you @Aruna that is exactly what I ended up doing and it did fit my requirements. I am sure the other suggestions are also correct but I have accepted this as the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You may instead use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function and implement your own logic, for example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.reduce(function (p, d, i) {
  return p + (i === fruits.length - 1 ? ' and ' : ', ') + d;
});
```

Comment: This is a better example for a general solution.

Comment: this works but it is needed a condition for the first item in the array, otherwise a comman will be prepended

`
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.reduce(function (p, d, i) {
  if(i === 0) {
    return d;
  }

  return p + (i === fruits.length - 1 ? ' and ' : ', ') + d;
});`

Comment: Please elaborate what `p`, `d` and `i` mean in this context. Those are poor variable names and don't convey the necessary meaning.

Comment: @analytical_prat looking at the `.reduce` syntax: 

p = accumulator, 
d = currentValue, 
i = currentIndex

Answer (score 5):

You can join the first 3 elements of the array using slice and join then append the last element concatenated with 'and'.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.slice(0, fruits.length - 1).join(', '); 
energy += ' and ' + fruits[fruits.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Function toSentence of [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/blob/master/toSentence.js) has the exact functionality you want. If you don't want to get whole library, you could just borrow `toSentence`:

```
function toSentence(array, separator, lastSeparator, serial) {
  separator = separator || ', ';
  lastSeparator = lastSeparator || ' and ';
  var a = array.slice(),
    lastMember = a.pop();

  if (array.length > 2 && serial) lastSeparator = separator + lastSeparator;

  return a.length ? a.join(separator) + lastSeparator + lastMember : lastMember;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a function to [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), unfortunately, so you do need to iterate through the loop and join it yourself:

```js
const array = ['banana', 'apple', 'taco']

let result = array[0]
for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (i < array.length - 1) {
    result += ', ' + array[i]
  } else {
    result += ' and ' + array[i]
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

You *could* make a function for this, though:

```js
// General purpose custom/dynamic join function creator.
function dynamicJoin(fn) {
  return function(array) {
    let result = array[0]
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      const joiner = fn(array[i - 1], array[i], i, array)
      result += joiner + array[i]
    }
    return result
  }
}

const joinCommaOrAnd = dynamicJoin(function(a, b, i, arr) {
  return (i === arr.length - 1) ? ' and ' : ', '
})

console.log(joinCommaOrAnd(['bread', 'fish', 'butter']))
```